# Farseer physics creates duplicate Body ID

Tags: c#, game-physics, farseer

Hello! I use this snippet to generate a `Body` and add to it the `World`. I add three bodies at program startup, which get correct `BodyID`. But when I attempt to add a body during runtime, it creates the body, but with the `BodyID` of `0`, which then affects the collision detection. Does anybody know ho this can be solved? (I tried setting the `BodyID` manually, but it says, that the setter is unaccessible). Thanks for help

```
                    ...
                    Body temp = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(pWorld, bd.width, bd.height, bd.density);
                    temp.SetTransform(bd.postition, 0f);

                    temp.BodyType = bt;
                    temp.OnCollision += OnCollision;
                    ...
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say  you attempt to add a body during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was that I was adding a body in another threat which caused probems of the physical World. I solved this by adding the bodies to a List and creating a PreUpdate method which collects the pending bodies and adds them to the world before each update.